# AWS S3 - ACL vs. CORS configuration vs. bucket/object permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, acl

It seems that Access Control Lists (ACL), CORS configurations, and the permissions for each bucket and object all come into play when configuring the access settings for S3 buckets/objects.

Can someone explain the difference between these and how they work together?

Comment: S3 documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_ACLs_UsingACLs.html

Comment: Yes I have been reading the docs. I was just looking for a succinct description of how each method is different from the others, as I haven't found this in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## S3 Bucket policies

They are the recommended way to configure access of a S3 bucket. A policy is a JSON document composed of statements. In each statement you either *Allow* or *Deny* an *action* to a Principal (the users affected by the policy).

## Access control lists

Considered legacy, they predate the implementation of bucket policies but they allow to set permission at a file level. For example if you want to restrict the access for a specific file within a bucket, but not the whole bucket, you will need to use ACLs.

## CORS Configuration

This a XML file to configure the CORS headers. You can choose to only allow http some methods (for example GET and POST) or all of them.

[More details in the AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html).

For more info about CORS: [What is CORS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

## IAM Policies

They are similar to Bucket policies, except you attach them an User, Group or Role, except of a bucket.

## Conflicts

In case of conflict between ACL/IAM policies/Bucket policies, for example if there both Allow and Deny applying to the same resource and user, the Deny always win.

The algorithm to resolve permission is basically:
 - If there is a Deny, Deny access
 - If there is an Allow, Allow access
 - If there isn't anything, Deny by default

## Best practices

Apply the principle of least privilege (don't allow access unless it's needed).
It's not recommended to attach policies directly to an User, but rather to create a group with the permission attached to it, then add the user to the group.
You can have for example a group Developer with full access on S3, a group Finance with read-only access.
If you need to restrict access to a bucket, use bucket policies.
Only use ACL if you need to configure access to individual files.

Comment: Can you use a bucket policy and then apply ACL on an item by item basis to create exceptions?